# jsPDF is not defined

Tags: vue.js, jspdf, referenceerror

I'm trying to use jsPDF with Vue but I get a `ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`. See the snippet :

```js
let jsPrint = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
  <button onclick="jsPrint()">
    print
  </button>
```

The script is linked in the `head` tag :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?= $site->title() ?> - <?= $page->title() ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= url('assets') ?>/css/style.css">

    <!--========== JSPDF ==========-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--========== VUE ==========-->
    <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/libs/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/app.js" type="module" defer></script>
</head>
```

Then in a component, I have a method that should be triggered on click on a button :

```
exportSimple: function() {
            const doc = new jsPDF()
            // const target = document.querySelector('#dialog-export-content')
            // doc.html(target, {
            //     callback: function(doc) {
            //         doc.save()
            //     },
            //     x: 10,
            //     y: 10
            // })
            
        }
```

But i throws an error.

I tried alternative methods to link the library : local, npm, other sources like    `jspdf.es.min.js`. Nothing works.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CDN the jsPDF object is available as property of `jspdf` which is available globally :

```
const { jsPDF } = jspdf
let print = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF()
}
```